# Test subscription is revoked by GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, subscription, auto-renewing

I'm working on a subscription renewal feature, in test mode, with testing payment methods. Problem is that we receive cancelation subscription webhook, GooglePlay makes subscription revoke. ​​
From params:

```
​"cancelReason": "1"
```

Status code from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions),

> Subscription was canceled by the system, for example, because of a
>   billing problem.

Also from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#Revoke)

> Revoking a subscription instantly removes access to the subscription
>   and is usually done when you or Google suspects fraud.

Usually, it sends cancelation webhook immediately after renewal, even when it was successful, so there are cases when I got two e-mails, about renewal success and cancelation. In my case renewal called after 5 minutes ([doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-subscriptions))

Have someone idea, what could be the reason? Is it some "Google anti-fraud system". Because for testing purpose we have short subscription period but the big price. But probably anti-fraud should not be executed when we do testing, with testing payment methods, when there is no real transaction.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was, that we didn't [acknowledge](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge) new subscriptions.
From the docs:

> If you use the Google Play Billing Library version 2.0 or newer, you
> must acknowledge all purchases within three days. Failure to properly
> acknowledge purchases results in those purchases being refunded.

Regarding subscriptions:

> For subscriptions, you must acknowledge any purchase that contains a
> new purchase token. This means that all initial purchases, plan
> changes, and re-signups need to be acknowledged, but you do not need
> to acknowledge subsequent renewals.

**Test acknowledging purchase with license testers:**

> For purchases made by license testers, the acknowledgment window is
> shorter. Instead of three days, ***purchases are refunded and revoked if
> they are not acknowledged within five minutes***.

**UPDATE**
changes in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test)

> You should also verify that purchases are properly acknowledged as
> described in processing purchases. For purchases from license testers, a > purchase will be refunded after 3 minutes if your app does not
> acknowledge the purchase and you will receive an email about the
> cancellation. You can also check the Orders tab in the Google Play
> Console to see if an order was refunded after 3 minutes.